# Adding phtml file to homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I create module in magento which will be adding my own phtml file to main page? Im really new in this :?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, don't need to develop extension for it.

Just go to your home page (cms page) and add this line anywhere you like:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/your_path/file_name.phtml"  name="myname"}}
```

However, it will depend what kind of info you will be adding in this file.